# How can I control the data rate of a peripheral?

Tags: java

I have an IMU that sends data to my computer at a rate of 100Hz. The data rate of the IMU cannot be changed and whenever the IMU is connected to the computer, the data is being sent. I want to change the data rate to 5Hz so I set up a counter and when the counter reaches a certain value, I process the last data sent. I suspect that this technique is causing some delay issues and is not practical. Is there another way for dealing with similar problems?
Please see the code for reference.
I first initiate the counters then call the function configure to start the communication with the IMU. whenever a new value is being sent, the counter reduces by one until it reaches one, then the value is getting used ( in this example I'm just logging the value into the console)

```
still = 1;
slst = new ArrayList<>();
ac = 0;
ac1 = 0;
ac2 = 118; // 1 sec
ac3 =118;

public void configure(RouteComponent source) {
                    source.stream(new Subscriber() {
                        @Override
                        public void apply(Data data, Object... env) {
                          h = data.value(EulerAngles.class).heading();
                          r = data.value(EulerAngles.class).roll();
                            if (ac>1){
                                ac--;
                            }
                            if(ac1>1){
                                ac1--;
                            }

                            if (ac==1 && ac1>1){
                               // ac2=3;
                              //  if(ac3==1) {
                                    still = 1;
                                    Log.i(String.valueOf(still));
                                stext.setText("Still");
                                    Log.i("Heading = ", String.valueOf(h));
                                vtext.setText(String.valueOf(h));
                                    ac = 0;
                             //   }
                               // if(ac3>1){
                               //     ac3--;
                              //  }
                            }
                            if(ac1==1) {
                                //if(ac2>1){
                                //   ac2--;
                                // }
                                // if(ac2==1){
                                // ac3=20;
                                //   if(ac2==1) {
                                still = 0; // active
                                Log.i( String.valueOf(still));
                                stext.setText("Active");
                                ac1 = 0;
                                ac = 0;
                                if (ac4 == 1) {
                                    ac4 = 4; //
                                }
                            }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated.  Wouldn't it be simpler to just throw out 19 out of 20 frames and capture the 20th?

Comment: How can I just throw 19 out of 20 frames without the use of counters?

Comment: You can't.  But you only need one counter to track it.  Count 20 frames, grab a frame, and reset the counter to zero.  Rinse, repeat.